# How to stop Drag Listener after Rectangle overlaps with each other

Tags: libgdx

Is anyone out there knows the problem in this code? I can still drag the ball even if the rectangles were already overlapsed.

```
ballRect = new Rectangle(ball.getBall().getX(),
ball.getBall().getY(), ball.getBall().getWidth(), ball.getBall().getHeight());
droidRect = new Rectangle(droid.getDroidX() + droid.getCurFrame().getRegionWidth()/2, droid.getDroidY() + droid.getCurFrame().getRegionHeight()/2, droid.getCurFrame().getRegionWidth() / 4, droid.getCurFrame().getRegionHeight() / 4);

if(droidRect.overlaps(ballRect)){

}
else{
    dragBall();
}
```

I've been working on this in an hour but I haven't solve this problem yet

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that `droidRect.overlaps()` is returning true?

Comment: Also, why are you dividing the droid's region's height and width?